# change magento decimal field format to use " . " instead of ","

Tags: currency-rates

I need to change decimal field format which uses '.' instead of ',' to separate decimal (and currency) numbers.

I use Dominican Republic pesos and our standard format is 1,000,000.00 system is showing like it was euro format.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The default setting for the number format is locale and is  in `System/Configuration/General/LocaleOptions/Locale`.

Magento doesn't seem to come with es_DO installed, so you could choose a similar locale that uses the same number format, e.g. es_MX (Mexico) or look into adding es_DO to magento.

Changing the locale will also change the translation file used, so es_MX may or may not be appropriate for you.